# Custom cron(5 8 * * *) function is not work in laravel task scheduling

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, cron

I am using laravel task scheduling and user this code in kernel file. I am using following code

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
            $emaiData = Lazer::table('emails_cron')->find(1);
            $result = explode('.', $emaiData->time);

           if($emaiData->type == "daily"){         
               $minutes  =       $result[1];
               $hours  =         $result[0];
               $daysOfMonths  =  '*';
               $months  =        '*';
               $daysOfWeeks  =   '*';
           }else{
               $minutes  =       $result[1];
               $hours  =         $result[0];;
               $daysOfMonths  =  '*';
               $months  =        '*';
               $daysOfWeeks  =   $emaiData->days;
           }
           $minutes = 58;
           $hours   = 9;
           //$min = 1;
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\PocketPos\BackOffice\BackOfficeApplicationController@cronTabExe')->cron("$minutes $hours * * *")->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/cron_log.log'));

    }
```

Above code not working. But When i add  `->cron("*/1 * * * *")` like this. it's working fine. 
[image]
please help in cron custom function add variable.

Thanks

Comment: Can you echo the value of `"$minutes $hours * * *"`?

Comment: @Wreigh thanks for reply yes variable above define $minutes = 58;
$hours   = 9; i am not know how to check the logs.can you guide me

Comment: just put `echo "$minutes $hours * * *";` below `$schedule->call` then run again schedule command.

Comment: @Wreigh  i have echo line but  where i show the these output.?

Comment: @Wreigh When controller is run email is sent but where i will show the variable string please

Comment: @Wreigh Where i am going wrong please?

Comment: @Wreigh i have set the server time then it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is due to server time difference.Try to add same time as current time zone. Hope  `cron("$minutes $hours * * *")` function will work.